# Does "copy and paste" exist as a verb in German?

Tags: verb

I wanted to tell a colleague "We can just copy and paste this from the other document", but suddenly got stuck wondering how this is actually said in German as a verb. Are any of the options below viable? If not, what's the correct term?

copy und paste,
copy und pasten,
kopierien und pasten

Comment: DId you try finding out for yourself, e.g. by googling? What did you find? Why did it not answer your question?

Comment: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Copy_and_paste

Comment: I have some doubts concerning the closing reason, since looking up the single verbs won't be sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

The standard phrase from ancient pre-computer times is:

> Wir können das aus dem anderen Dokument übernehmen.

*Kopieren und einfügen* is practically never used, probably due to the number of syllables, the next-used solution is *copy/paste* (pronounced as in English but without *and*) more used like a substantive, since pressing it into any German conjugation is awkward. In fact the low-level process of Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V is often not talked about anyway.

Comment: You can even go full anglicism and just say "Wir können das aus dem anderen Dokument copypasten. "

Comment: Statt 'übernehmen' kann man auch (nur) 'einfügen' nutzen. Das Kopieren versteht sich dann

Comment: Wir können das plagiieren.

Comment: In my environment I often hear "grabsch und patsch" and everybody understands it immediately as a humourous rendering of "copy and paste".